# Como detectar si un modelo en django tuvo cambios

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo un modelo y debo detectar si este tiene cambios en alguno de sus campos al ejecutar el método `save` y ejecutar una función en caso de que si tenga cambios, de lo contrario la función no debe ejecutarse.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Persona(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name=_('nombre'))
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name=_('nombre'))
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=80,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name=_('nombre'))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if cambios_detectados:
            self.enviar_mail()
        return super(Negocio, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, una por ejemplo es utilizar señales [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save) o [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) (cabe recalcar que no sabrás con exactitud si un campo de la instancia a sido modificado):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender = 'your_app.MyModel')
def signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created'): self.enviar_mail()
```

La forma definitiva de hacerlo, **sabiendo si se a modificado un campo y la mas optima**, es de la siguiente manera (utilizando la señal [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender = 'your_app.MyModel')
def signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        old_instance = sender.objects.get(pk = instance.pk)
        if old_instance.email != instance.email: self.enviar_mail()
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

`old_instance` es la instancia "vieja" por asi decirlo, **ya que aun no a sido actualizada**, por eso sabemos con certeza si sea modificado el campo `email` (también puede ser otro).

---

*(las siguientes alternativas no te las recomiendo)*

Otra forma, es pasarle un argumento posicional al método `save` que indique que es así:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if args[0]:
        print('Hola!') 
        self.enviar_mail()
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

```
>>> i = Persona.objects.get(...)
>>> i.email = ...
>>> i.save(True)
Hola!
```

Intente hacerlo con argumentos de palabra clave que seria lo ideal (ya que esta forma no me convence) pero no funciona pues da error.

También hay que mencionar que según la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save) al momento de guardar un objeto en la db, la única "forma" de saber cuando una instancia es modificada, es atraves de la señal [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) y [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save).

---

Por otra parte otra forma es pasarle al método `save` el argumento de palabra clave [`update_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('update_fields'):
        print('Hola!')
        self.eviar_email()

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

```
>>> i = Persona.objects.get(...)
>>> i.email = ...
>>> i.save(update_fields=['email'])
Hola!
```

O el método `save` puede ser así:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'email' in kwargs.get('update_fields'):
        print('Hola!')
        self.eviar_email()

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

La desventaja de hacerlo de esta manera es que **si o si tienes que siempre pasarle el argumento de palabra clave [`update_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) al método `save`**, también cabe recalcar que las señales `post_save` y `pre_save` reciben el argumento `update_fields`, así que puedes hacer esto en las señales también.

Y listo eso seria todo, según lo que he investigado serian las únicas maneras de hacerlo, y lo que yo te recomiendo es utilizar señales.

Espero haberte ayudado.